# expected status code in (200-299) got 503

Tags: ios

I got the following error 
expected status code in (200-299) got 503.

I didn't get this all the time. Sometimes I notice this error. I am unable to figure out the exact reason.

The base URL I am using in the application is in following format.

BaseURL: https://staging.something.com

For every request I append to base url as follows.

"BaseURL/api/"

Please let me know if any issues.

Comment: First of all, get familiar with HTTP [response codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Then look for the place where `you` generate the error and handle it properly from there.

Answer (score 3):

503 means service unavailable. Lots of servers give that for lots of reasons.

2xx means that something normal happened

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

503 means ["Service Unavailable"](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html).

Which means there is a problem on the server side.

Make certain that the URL you are connecting to looks like a valid URL.  For example, you can do something like:

```
NSLog(@"the url I am connecting to is %@", [myURL absoluteString]);
```

And see if it matches what you were expecting:  `https://staging.something.com/api/`.

If it looks really wrong, like "`apihttps://staging.something.com`", then it's something that you can easily fix.

If you are getting this problem all the time, you should probably reach out to the owner of the service you're trying to use and ask them for assistance.